# Librería SSD1306 MicroPython no me funciona

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, micropython, raspberry

[image: Error de libreria]

Estoy aprendiendo micropython usando una raspberry Pi Pico, nos pidieron instalar la siguiente librería (que corresponde a una pantalla oled) pero nos sale el error de la imagen ¨ropython-ssd1306-0.3.tar.gz does not appear to be a Python project: neither 'setup.py' nor 'pyproject.toml' found.
Error: process returned with code 1¨